# Determine via C# whether a File Path is valid and exists

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, path

I am building a WinForms application that receives a path from a user via a `SaveFileDialog`.

Here is the relevant portion of my code. How can I determine if the path `pcapFile` is valid and exists?

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialogBrowse = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialogBrowse.Filter = "Pcap file|*.pcap";
    saveFileDialogBrowse.Title = "Save an pcap File";
    saveFileDialogBrowse.ShowDialog();
    pcapFile = saveFileDialogBrowse.FileName; //do whatever you like with the selected filename

    if (pcapFile != "")
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(pcapFile);
        tbOutputFileName.Text = fileInfo.FullName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FileInfo` will throw an exception if the path provided to it is malformed.  If you want to know if that file already exists check the `FileInfo.Exists` property.

Answer (score 9):

Please use [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) method. It won't throw an exception. From MSDN:

> **true** if the caller has the required permissions and *path* contains the name of an existing file; otherwise, **false**. This method also returns **false** if *path* is **null**, an invalid path, or a zero-length string. If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns **false** regardless of the existence of *path*.

Answer (score 0):

use the `FileInfo` constructor.

> It will throw a `ArgumentException` if The file name is empty,
>   contains only white spaces, or contains invalid characters. It can
>   also throw SecurityException

or use `Path.GetInvalidPathChars` Method

> it Gets an array containing the characters that are not allowed in path
>   names.

// Get a list of invalid file characters.

```
char[] invalidFileChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
```